# Nginx logs are not shown

Tags: docker, nginx, logging

I have a docker running nginx with port forward to 8080

All I want is to see the logs in nginx when I hit

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

(I get an answer but I want to see logs)

Both access.log and error.log and enabled from /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Neither tail -f  access.log nor cat access.log works. All I get is an empty line:

```
root@fe0f47477548:/var/log/nginx# cat access.log

^C
root@fe0f47477548:/var/log/nginx#
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The NGINX docker distribution redirects (`soft links`) logging to the stdout/stderr

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Feb 17 19:20 access.log -> /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Feb 17 19:20 error.log -> /dev/stderr
```

**From Docker host**

You can access the logs using Docker logs

```
docker logs nginx
```

**From inside the Docker container**

It is possible to remove the log forwarding which is defined in the standard NGINX Docker Image.
This requires creating a custom Dockerfile (ie `mynginx`) but it is a simple change

```
FROM nginx:latest

# drop symlinks
RUN unlink /var/log/nginx/access.log
RUN unlink /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

When running the newly defined container the log files can be seen in `/var/logs/nginx`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 491 Feb 19 13:14 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 19 13:14 error.log

root@ca2472f28be5:/var/log/nginx# cat access.log
72.25.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2021:13:15:55 +0000] "GET 
/static/js/main.f81cbe58.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost/" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: Yup I know that but I was looking for a way to see logs from inside the docker.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include this case (it needs a simple customisation)

Comment: Can you please take a look on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66318024/nginx-read-secret-and-webhook-headers