# Nginx read secret and webhook headers

Tags: nginx, github, proxy, reverse-proxy

A Webhook from Github is passing through Nginx proxy.

The webhook uses secret and the header is sent as X-Hub-Signature-256.

I want to make Nginx filtering requests, i.e I need Nginx to take the webhook header value and compare it to $SECRET_TOKEN. If the secret is right, it will send 200 and If not, 403.

I thought of something like this, but could find a way to implement it:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;

  location /payload {
      
      #Read the header sent by the webhook (header name: X-Hub-Signature-256)
      #If the header content matches $SECRET_TOKEN I defined on Nginx then return 200
      #Else, return 403 
  }
}
```

Please help with implementing this pseudo as I couldn't find any example online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, I would include this logic in the webhook itself (it is going to be easier to code it and maintain, it also makes sense in case one day the same NGINX starts serving other services).